How to rollback(execute down) in TypeORM migration automatically in case of error?
We are using TypeORM migrations in one of our NestJS projects.
Following is the example format of migration script that we are using.
import {MigrationInterface, QueryRunner} from "typeorm";

export class VMTestTableTwo1713851442445 implements MigrationInterface {

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {

      await queryRunner.query(`
        CREATE TABLE "vm_test"(
          "aggregate_id" uuid NOT NULL
        );
      `);
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
      await queryRunner.query(`
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "vm_test";
      `);
    }
}


If a up script fails, ideally the down should get executed automatically. But, this is not the case with TypeORM migration. If I am not wrong, Sequelize migration works that way.
How to achieve this in TypeORM migration?
UPDATE:
export default TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
    return {
      type: 'postgres',
      host: <host>,
      port: <port>,
      username: <username>,
      password: <pwd>,
      database: <db>,
      synchronize: false,
      logging: EnvChecker.queryLogger() ? ['query', 'error'] : false,
      migrationsRun: true,
      migrations: [
        `${__dirname}/../migrations/*{.ts,.js}`
      ],
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      entities: [
        `${__dirname}/../**/domain/entities/*.entity{.ts,.js}`
      ],
      extra: {
        max: <maxPool>,
        connectionTimeoutMillis: <connectionTimeoutMillis>,
        idleTimeoutMillis: <config.get('idleTimeoutMillis')>
      },
      migrationsTransactionMode: 'each'
    };
  },
  inject: [ConfigService]
});


Your migrations will be executed in a transaction, so if something fail the transaction will not be committed and it will be rollback automatically without using your down.
Your down is not here to rollback in case of error but to allow you to revert your modifications later on. For example, if you change your mind or if you switch to another branch where the migration should not apply.
More on how transactions are used by TypeORM: https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/migrations#transaction-modes

Understood. The main problem we are facing is that the app crashes if an up script fails. I understand that the script needs to be tested before going in prod but due to data issues it failed. I need the connection to recover. I have updated the main question with the module code.

I think it's an expected behavior and not directly link to TypeORM.
Because if the migration fails the app will not be able to work correctly. For example if you were supposed to add a new table but it failed, the app will still try to use this table but because it doesn't exist it will crash.
I guess the solution would be to automatically cancel the deployment, and go back to the previous version, but it will depends on how you deploy your app. Kubernetes, CI/CD tools and Cloud providers usually offers this possibility but I'm no expert in this

Agreed. I came to the same conclusion. Thank you.
